# What bike should I get? For forests and city mainly

Tags: mountain-bike

So right now I've got a hard tail but I'm not really happy with it. At the moment I'm only riding my bike in the city even though I am planning on riding it in the forest and parks as well. My question is what bike to get. Should I get an enduro bike, downhill or whatever is best for the above mentioned categories.
That being said, I don't have any mountain biking experience but I know how to ride it well.

Or should I keep my bike which I am using right now?

I hope you guys can help me and thank you already so much for your help!

Have you got a suggestion for a new bike? price range up to 700 Dollar/Pound/Euro please

Comment: A bike that’s good in the city is different to a bike that’s good on the trails, compromise on neither and get two bikes!

Comment: Mountain biking is very different from riding on roads. With no experience, I strongly suggest you start on the Green trails and work up to the triple black diamonds, not the other way round.

Comment: What don't you like about your hardtail? It could be the wrong size for you (or adjusted wrong). It could have unsuitable tyres so it's hard work on the road but still lacks grip on the trails.

Comment: The best bike is the one you WANT to ride.  It is comfortable to ride and doesn't hurt you or scare you.    And that can be completely different for any two people.  Just ride what you like.  That may mean getting a leg over several different styles of bike.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anyone who can tell you what you will like.

It's all about the test ride.
If there is any way you can rent/borrow or test ride at the bike shop lots of different bikes to get a feel for the differences in the different kinds of bikes it's the best way to know what you want/need.

It's all about trade offs and the best way to know is to get out and try things. Build up your knowledge of how different bikes feel so you can make an informed decision.

Sometimes you can get something you really like by going to wider or narrower tires and a different seat.